# Angular 8 routing, cant navigate to component without a name before slash

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, frontend

By default, I want the browser to navigate to **LandingPageComponent** on opening.

e.g. http://localhost:4200/

When users input after the slash, I want to navigate to **ProfileComponent** with parameters in the URL

e.g. http://localhost:4200/user1

is this method possible? Since I am getting and error of "Path cannot start with a slash".

```
app-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [

  {path:'', component:LandingPageComponent},
  {path: '/:profileId',
  loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#profileModule'
}, 
];
```

```
profile-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [

{path:'', component:profileComponent},   //< I want to load this component after /user1
{path :'folder/:folderId', component:FolderComponent},
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {path:'', component:LandingPageComponent},
  {path: ':profileId',
  loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#profileModule'
}, 
];
```

Remove '/' from path of profileId and try.